# Problems with jMyCarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, mousewheel

I'm completely stuck as to how to fix this. When I test it offline it works great. When I upload it and run it live none the images on my site load unless you click on the link for the page a second time. And on the press page it loads for a second and then its the same as the other pages but a second click on the link doesn't fix it. I've checked out this problem in firefox and safari.

P.S. I know my Menu's still are having issues if anyone has any suggestions for that I'd be super thankful. Mainly how can I get the hidden menu to stay centered.

Thanks!!!!!

http://www.tracyashaw.com/e2studio/index.html 
http://www.tracyashaw.com/e2studio/press.hmtl

This on on the top of each page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="e2studio.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jMyCarousel.js"></script>
<!-- Optional -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".jMyCarousel").jMyCarousel({
            visible: '100%'
        });
    });
</script>

    <script>

var myimages=new Array()
function preloadimages(){
for (i=0;i<preloadimages.arguments.length;i++){
myimages[i]=new Image()
myimages[i].src=preloadimages.arguments[i]
}
}


//Enter path of images to be preloaded inside parenthesis. Extend list as desired.
preloadimages("images/home_1.jpg","images/newport.jpg","images/newport_life.jpg","images/RI_monthly.jpg","images/unique_homes.jpg","images/ri_monthly_cover.jpg","images/so_ri_press_cover.jpg","images/grace_ormonde_cover.jpg")

</script>
```

Comment: You should post your code here, and not a link to your code.  Once that link id dead, this question will be of no use to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery mousewheel plug-in you are using clearly states in the header comments that jQuery 1.2.2+ is required, likely due to the dependency on the `special` property of jQuery's event object.  You have `link`ed to jQuery 1.2.1.  Also some image requests are coming back with a 404 response code.  You'll have to address these two items.

Comment: I've upgraded jQuery and the problem still persists. Although the images now show up on the press page as well I didn't notice the 404 before.